# Align center in flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to align text to center, but if text take two lines it's not work. See the picture. Text in white work fine but in blue don't work.

```
Container(
        decoration: new BoxDecoration(color: Color(int.parse(bgColor.replaceAll('#', '0xff')))),
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 100, 0, 100),
        child: ParsedText(
        text: text,
        style: part == "big" ? TextStyle(
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            fontSize: 30,
            color: color
        ):
        TextStyle(
          color: Colors.black
        ),
        parse: <MatchText>[
          MatchText(
            type: ParsedType.URL,
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue,),
            onTap: (url) async{
              url = "http://"+url.replaceAll("https://", "");
              if (await canLaunch(url)) await launch(url);
            }
          )
        ]
    ),
)
```

[image]

Comment: It would be much easier if you had put the simple string instead of your `ParsedText`, `MatchedText` etc stuff.

Comment: I have to use `ParsedText` and `MatchedText ` because i want to test if my text contain url to create a clickable link

Comment: `textAlign: TextAlign.center`

Comment: I don't use `Text()` so `textAlign: TextAlign.center` not work

Comment: Check below answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
ParsedText(
   alignment: TextAlign.center,
   // ...
),
```